# Non Identifying or Identifying

Tags: mysql

Cannot undestand main idea of identifying relationships please can you help me with this example..

Example: Supplier may have many Reception and reception can have a single Supplier

There cant be a Reception without a Supplier so does this means it has to be a identifying? or it can be a non identifying since the Supplier its only used once and it wont be repeated. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is One to many Relationship between Suppliers and Reception ("supplies"). As one supplier can supply to many Reception But One Reception can be supplied by only one supplier.

Yes! It has to be identifying relationship. You should include all related Reception's Id in the Supplier relation.

Comment: Yes it is that... but should i use an identifying or non identifying relation??